# CSS3 transition rotate in Safari

Tags: css, css-transitions

On all browsers the below code functions well, but it doesn't in Safari. I'm also unable to find a good answered question like this on Stack, am I missing something?

http://jsfiddle.net/pw13yd3x/1/

```
.containerLinksBlock {
    background-color:red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    -ms-transition: border-radius 0.6s, transform 1.6s;
    -webkit-transition:border-radius 0.6s, transform 1.6s;
    -o-transition: border-radius 0.6s, transform 1.6s;
    transition:border-radius 0.6s, transform 1.6s;
}
.containerLinksBlock:hover {
    border-radius:0px 42px 0px 42px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(420deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(420deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(420deg);
    transform: rotate(420deg);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `-webkit` prefix in the transitions too.

```
-webkit-transition:border-radius 0.6s, -webkit-transform 1.6s;
```

Comment: Aha, so the complete correct code (also for other browsers) is: http://jsfiddle.net/pw13yd3x/2/

Comment: Yeah, see http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions and http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d.